# Android retrofit, retrieve only secondary object array

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Having a json like the next, I would like to retrieve only the results object. I am using Retrofit and Gson in Android. Is it possible or must I retrieve the entire json and create two models? If so, how should I configure the interface class? Thanks in advance.

```
{
  page: 1,
  total_results: 10000,
  results: [
     {
         adult: false,
         id: 791373,
         original_language: "en",
         original_title: "Zack Snyder's Justice League",
         popularity: 11783.352,
         release_date: "2021-03-18",
         video: false,
         vote_average: 8.7,
         vote_count: 3389
     },
     {
         adult: false,
         id: 581389,
         original_language: "ko",
         original_title: "Seungriho",
         popularity: 3507.528,
         release_date: "2021-02-05",
         video: false,
         vote_average: 7.2,
         vote_count: 416
     },
     {
         adult: false,
         id: 527774,
         original_language: "en",
         original_title: "Raya and the Last Dragon",
         popularity: 3067.315,
         release_date: "2021-03-03",
         video: false,
         vote_average: 8.4,
         vote_count: 1613
     }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Appending my actual code, I use Java. I get this error: "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $".

Model Movie:

```
public class Movie {
   
   private Boolean adult;
   @SerializedName("id")
   @Expose
   private Integer id;
   private String original_language;
   @SerializedName("original_title")
   @Expose
   private String title;
   private Integer popularity;
   @SerializedName("release_date")
   @Expose
   private String date;
   private Boolean video;
   private Double vote_average;
   private Integer vote_count;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Class RetrofitClient:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        String baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                     .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Retrofit Interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("movie/popular?api_key=mykey")
    Call<ArrayList<Movie>> getMovies();

}
```

And finally MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getMovies();
    }

    private void getMovies() {
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient();;
        ApiService Apiservice = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

        Call<ArrayList<Movie>>  call = Apiservice.getMovies();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Movie>> call, Response<ArrayList<Movie>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    String code = "Error Code: " + response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),code,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                ArrayList<Movie> MovieList = response.body();

                for (Movie movie: MovieList) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "id: " + movie.getId() + "\n";
                    content += "Title: " + movie.getTitle() + "\n";
                    content += "Date: " + movie.getDate() + "\n\n";
                    texto.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<EntidadPelicula>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have to put in all the fields of both models.  Just the ones you care about.  GSON can be set to ignore the others.

Comment: are you using java or  kotlin ?

Comment: is your problem how to generate the pojo classes or what ?

Comment: I use java. My problem is retrieving data from json. The error is `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`. I don't know how to retrieve only `results` object and don't retrieve `page` and `total_results` fields.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to retrieve the `page` and `total_results` field.

you can just make your model like this

```
data class ResultResponse(val results : List<Movie>)
```

Comment: That is kotlin, right? sorry, I use Java, my fault don't to say it.